# Is it possible to add a CNAME to a service like Amazon SES?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns

I'm developing a web app that connects mail clients to Amazon SES via SMTP (and runs sending reports, etc), and in those mail clients I currently have to use this:

email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

as the server and sometimes have to ask users to put that into their SMTP server settings as well. I was wondering if instead of using that long domain, if I could create a CNAME for a domain I already own, say: ses.example.com and point it to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com so that the user's have an easy to remember server address? Or do you think that would cause problems?

Comment: *"users have an easy to remember server address"*...? Wait, what "users" are putting the SES hostname in as their SMTP server, and why?  Your plan seems to have a giant hole unrelated to typing long hostnames.

Comment: Not easy to remember, but more of a white label-y solution, easy to type / copy paste / etc. The application has some massive limitations working with other applications where it needs to be input manually based on techincal limitations that I'm hoping i can resolve eventually but for now this is all I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Works great.  Amazon has to allow standard DNS functions else they'd be pretty lame.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Here's another good one on when to use Host versus Alias

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

-Chase

Comment: Caveat: make sure the certificate used has all names you'll be using else your mail client may terminate due to name mismatch...

Comment: 1. All the names? More than just covering ses.example.com?

Comment: 2. Yeah, I knew it was possible in CloudFront but was wondering if there were any caveats to doing it for Amazon SES.

Comment: Thanks so muck for the links though, they help me feel more comfortable implementing this since Amazon seems to talk about it openly - even if not direclty in the context of SES.

Comment: The nice thing CNAME's are standardized across enough DNS servers, that if you can do it, you can expect it to work as expected.  If they deviated between Route 53 and other offerings.... they'd be in hot water.

Comment: And per the SMTP comments, it's totally cool to do that.  This is how you could build a tenanted applicaiton, CNAMING vanity domains to a set of SES servers, and let the application route the incoming mail based on domain.  And as long as the reverse DNS lookup was validated in SPF/DMARC, it'll all work great.